# the number of ordered triplets(x,y,z) such that x,y,z are primes and (x^y) +1=z

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

> the number of ordered triplets$(x,y,z)$ such that $x,y,z$ are primes and $(x^y) +1=z$

> Options $(0,1,2,\infty$ many)

i tried that since they are prime and all primes except 2 are odd.
so a $prime^{prime}$ will be odd (except$2$), and since $z$ cant be even (prime), so $x =2$
so the equation now is $(2^n)+1=z$. I have no idea how to get any further. any help would be appreciated

Comment: Take a look ar Fermat primes.

Comment: Under what conditions can you factor $x^n+1$, Aayush?

Comment: @GerryMyerson sorry I am not able to understand what conditions do you mean, all that has been given in the question is that x,y,z are primes that's it, and that x^y+1=z should work for those primes.

Comment: OK, can you factor $x^3+1$, Aayush? (but I think Angelica has explained things).

Comment: yeah i got it Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Recall that

$$a^3+b^3=(a+b)(a^2-ab+b^2)$$

and notice that

$$a^5+b^5=(a+b)(a^4-a^3b+a^2b^2-ab^3+b^4)$$

Compare your equation $x^y+1=z$ to the form $a^n+b^n$ (ie replace $a,b,n$ with numbers or variables), and see if you can find a way to generalize this for all odd $n$.